# Thread blocked waiting for a signal

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, signals

sIn my application, I try to catch a specific signal which is SIGUSR1, I wrote the below code to do this issue, in which the application will create a thread for "init_signal_catcher".

The problem is when I run the code ,the program goes to sleep forever and does not respond to any signal even if it is SIGUSR1.

So could you please tell me what is the problem in my below code?

**Note:** The below can be run directly without having to create a thread, just replace the function name init_signal_catcher with main.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Value of the last signal caught */
volatile sig_atomic_t sig_value;

static void sig_handler(const int sig_number, siginfo_t *sig_info, void *context)
{
if (sig_number == SIGSEGV)
{
    error_sys("Error at address 0x%lx", (long)sig_info->si_addr);
    exit(-1);
}
sig_value = sig_number;
}


int init_signal_catcher()
{
struct sigaction sig_action; /* Structure describing the action to be taken when asignal arrives.  */

sigset_t oldmask;  /* Signal mask before signal disposition change.      */
sigset_t newmask;  /* Signal mask after signal disposition change.       */
sigset_t zeromask; /* Signal mask to unblock all signal while suspended. */

/* Define signal mask and install signal handlers */
memset(&sig_action, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));

sig_action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
sig_action.sa_sigaction = sig_handler;

/* Examine and change a signal action. */
sigaction(SIGHUP, &sig_action, NULL);
sigaction(SIGINT, &sig_action, NULL);
sigaction(SIGTERM, &sig_action, NULL);
sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sig_action, NULL);
sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sig_action, NULL);

    /* Block SIGHUP, SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGSEGV and SIGUSR1 signals. */
sigemptyset(&newmask);
sigaddset(&newmask, SIGHUP);
sigaddset(&newmask, SIGINT);
sigaddset(&newmask, SIGTERM);
sigaddset(&newmask, SIGSEGV);
sigaddset(&newmask, SIGUSR1);

/* Examine and change blocked signals. */
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newmask, &oldmask);

/* Initialize the empty signal set. */
sigemptyset(&zeromask);
sig_value = 0;

while ((sig_value != SIGINT) && (sig_value != SIGTERM))
{
    sig_value = 0;

    /*
     * Go to sleep (unblocking all signals) until a signal is catched.
     * On return from sleep, the signals SIGHUP, SIGINT, SIGTERM and
         * SIGUSR1 are again blocked.
     */
        printf("Suspending on %lu mask.", zeromask);

        // Wait for a signal.
    sigsuspend(&zeromask);

    switch(sig_value)
    {
                printf("Caught Signal %d", sig_value);
        case SIGUSR1:
                    printf("Caught SIGUSR1");
                    break;
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have bad news for you. Your code works very well on my system. I have no idea what's wrong on yours. Try adding `\n` to `printf` formats, maybe?

Comment: Ditto.  It runs as expected.

Comment: @user58697 you are correct I added \n at the end of printf and it works as expected. But why adding \n changes everything?

My problem now is, I integrate this code into a bigger code with multiple threads, and it does not work at all there even if I add \n to the printf

Comment: It doesn't change anything, it just forces the buffer to flush and you see the results you were not seeing before.

Comment: @Duck In my original program as I said this part does not work. Now I tried something new ,in which in the sig_handler I print the number of the signal, and it works perfectly. Whenever I signal the process with a specific signal, the sig_handler prints the number of the received signal, but the problem is the program does not do any printing or execution for the functions inside the while loop. What could be the possible reason?

The while code is exactly the same in both the above test and the original program.

Comment: The main original code is written in C++ and being compiled using b2 tool from boost, whereas this part since it only contains C code, I compiled it with gcc compiler. So does this may have an effect?

Comment: @HA-AS, but you are threading it now, right?  So one thread is running init_signal_catcher and others, including main, are doing something else?  If so, you need to block the signals in all other threads so the signals are specifically delivered to the init_signal_catcher thread.  Otherwise any thread can catch the signal and sigsuspend will sit there blocking if it doesn't catch the signal.

Comment: But @Duck are you sure I have to explicitly block the signals in all other threads? Because doing this will complicate more my application. I have a random number of threads depending on requests issued by users.

Comment: I tried now, to run only one thread in the whole process, and my application was able to catch the signals and the while loop worked correctly.

Comment: Basically the signals get sent to the process which picks a random thread to deliver it to.  If you block the signals in the other threads the OS is forced to deliver them to thread you want.  It doesn't have to be complicated.  Assume you start threads from main.  Start and set up the signal handling thread.  Block main.  Any further threads started from main will inherit its signal mask and the signals are automatically blocked in them.